# Javascript transfer information from one page to another

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a page when you input a number and then on a separate page it displays the multiplication of that number up to and including 10.  I can get it to display the table on a new page with document.write but with no formatting and still using the same URL as the first.  So far I have tried:

window.location.href
location.href
return

Original Page: Assignment2_Input.html

Result Page: Assignment2_Outpul.html

Script: Assignment2Script.js

Any help would be appreciated!

Orginal Page:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Input</title>
<link href="Assignment2InputStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    <h2>Assignment 2</h2>
    <h1>Multiplication Table</h1>
    <form method="post"><label id="NumberLabel">Please Enter Number:         </label><input id="Number" type="text" size="25"></form>
    <br/>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Calculate" > 
    <p></p>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<script src="Assignment2_Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Result Page: (This is the format I am going for on this URL)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Input</title>
<link href="Assignment2InputStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="title">
    <h2>Assignment 2</h2>
    <h1>Multiplication Table</h1>
    <form method="post"><label id="NumberLabel">Please Enter Number:     </label><input id="Number" type="text" size="25"></form>
    <br/>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Calculate" > 
    <p></p>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<script src="Assignment2_Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function calculate() {
num = document.getElementById("Number").value;
document.write('<body background-color="aqua">');
document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
document.write("<tr><td>" + num + " x " + i + " = " + num*i + "</td></tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");
}
```

I now have the code working in Chrome(still does not work in Firefox)

However when it switched to the new page it flashes the table up for a second and then it disappears.  Any thoughts?

Comment: [**What you need**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: You could also set a cookie with the information you need and then get it for the next page, but I'd say +1 to @SpYk3HH comment using local storage =).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.